# encoding error message

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, error-handling

I'm getting this error in the console: "The character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it". I'm having trouble understanding the issue here. I double checked to make sure that the file names that I'm linking to are correct. Also, as far as I'm aware my meta tag is appropriate. Any help is appreciated.

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="modernizr.js"></script>
   <script>
        Modernizr.load([
           "features.js",
           {
               test: Modernizr.geolocation,
               yep: "geolocation.js",
               nope: "noGeolocation.js"
               },
           {
               test: Modernizr.localstorage,
               yep: "localStorage.js",
               nope: "noLocalStorage.js"                             
             },
           {
               test: Modernizr.rgba,
               yep: "rgbaTest.js",
               nope: "norgbaTest.js",
               complete: function() {
                 init();
               }
             }            
          ]);
  </script>
```

Comment: Looks like this error is not related to your script.  Does this error still happens if you remove the script?

Answer (score 0):

> The character encoding of a **framed document**

It says not about your document but about "framed document". Perhaps some of these scripts creates iframe. And this iframe has no metatag with encode declaration.